# How to turn on the location of the device while the application is starting?

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap

The config.xml file of my phonegap application is below.
How can I turn on the location of the device while the application is starting?

```xml
<description>
  Online Abonelik, Borç Sorgulama, Fatura Ödeme, Tüketim Sorgulama v.b. pek çok işlem
</description>

<author href="http://www.infopark.com.tr" email="bilgi@infopark.com.tr">
  Infopark
</author>

<preference name="permission" value="none" />

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="2.4.2" source="npm" />

<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation" />


<preference name="orientation" value="default" />
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustResize" />



<feature name="StatusBar">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true" />
</feature>


<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.5.0" />

<icon src="uedasicon.png" />

<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />

<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleShortVersionString">
  <string>107</string>
</gap:config-file>


<access origin="*" />


<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1.1.0" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" />

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://testoim.com.tr" />
<platform name="android">
  <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
  <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>

</widget>
```

Comment: `How can I turn on the location of the device while the application is starting?` It's not clear what you mean by this. Do you mean you want to ensure the device location setting (Location Mode on Android/Location Services on iOS) is enabled when your app first starts?

Comment: yes, if the locaiton is off, it must be alerted and turned on

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) to check if location setting is currently enabled using [isLocationEnabled()](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#islocationenabled) and you can monitor realtime changes in the location setting using [registerLocationStateChangeHandler()](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#registerlocationstatechangehandler).

It is not possible on either Android or iOS to programmatically switch on the device location setting with the user's explicit consent.

However, on Android you can use [cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy) to programmatically request that location mode be switched on or accuracy level increased.
This presents the user with a system dialog "Improve location accuracy?" - the have to press "Yes" in order for it to be applied.

On iOS, it is not programmatically possible to switch Location Services ON or to directly open the Location Services page in the Settings app. The best than can be done (using `cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy`) is to display a native iOS system dialog which gives user the option of directly opening the Privacy page in the Settings app which contains the switch to turn Location Services ON.